# How to replace part of a file name with another name in batch processing

Tags: batch-file, batch-processing

I have been trying to replace a part of some file names in a directory to new names.  I have found many examples regarding this replacement using `REN` command with a for loop.

Example: if I want to replace test001 to test003, I can replace using `REN`.

But what,if I take 001 and 003 as user input through set `\p` command and I want the output to be test003, for the input test001.

I have the following files in my folder:

> Test001.txt
>   user001.txt
>   fjkdjdl001.txt

I want to convert them to

> Test0003.txt
>   user003.txt
>   and so on.

But 001,003 are user inputted.

How for+ren act with user inputted characters.Please help me.

Comment: Try `ren *%src%` *%dest%` where `src` and `dest` are input from a `set /p src=...` and `set /p dest=...`

Comment: For some reason,Its syntax error.can you write a FOR loop?

Comment: Please check where I went wrong?  `code` REN "*%src%.sh" "*%dest%.sh" acc' to what you suggested and my src=991 and my dest=998.Initially my filename was Test991.sh but now,its test9998.sh.why is this extra 9 coming and where from it is coming?Iam surprised.And How can I remove this character which is appearing in some filenames?Please help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the following commands in a batch file, say `sample.bat`

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
set /p "string1=Enter the sequence to be replaced : "
set /p "string2=Enter the new sequence  : "
for %%F in (*%string1%.*) do (
  set "filename=%%F"
  ren "!filename!" "!filename:%string1%=%string2%!"
)
```

You can execute this batch file from the command prompt using the following command:

> **sample.bat**

Comment: If any needs to modify multiple files with pattern just use the code provided by Infinite Recursion, only modifiy the *%string1%.** with *%string1%**.*

Answer (score 6):

Often times you do need a small batch script to execute some seemingly simple rename operations. However, you only need the REN command in this case.

```
ren *001.txt *03.txt
```

See [How does the Windows RENAME command interpret wildcards?](https://superuser.com/q/475874/109090) for an explanation as to why this works.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.But I don't want src and dest to be hardcoded.I want them as input from the users.Don't know why an extra '9' is coming and how I can remove it.